# Tasks pending forever with Celery, RabbitMQ and statsmodels

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, statsmodels

I am trying to distribute some linear regression tasks using Celery with RabbitMQ. The setup works fine with the example add(x,y) function, but when I instantiate the statsmodels OLS class, e.g.

```
self.model = sm.OLS(self.y, self.X)
```

the worker is pending indefinitely while consuming 100% CPU.

What is going on?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default celery uses the multiprocessing library as the concurrency implementation. StatsModels' OLS method makes a call to Lapack, which (along with many functions in Lapack / BLAS) starts its own thread pool to speed up calculations. Unfortunately threads don't inherit after a subprocess has been forked, so a zombie is created.

Here's a discussion in Celery issues:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1842

But as the last post points out, it's not Celery's fault.

There's a long discussion about the problem on OpenBLAS' issues:
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/294

Hopefully this won't be an issue in the future because the default builds of OpenBLAS are now fork-safe:
http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Default-builds-of-OpenBLAS-development-branch-are-now-fork-safe-td36523.html

(As of Feb 9, 2014- you may need to upgrade your version or install the latest dev build).

#### Two workarounds:

- Use the thread process pool in celery (the default is prefork). The option is --pool=threads
- Don't use functions that rely on Lapack or BLAS. A pure-python implementation of linear regression is available in scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html, for example