# Debug forever pending Celery task calling OptaPy

Tags: django, celery, python-multithreading, optapy

I try running [OptaPy](https://github.com/optapy/optapy) in a Celery task from within a Django application using Redis as a broker. The task is received by the Celery worker, but remains `PENDING` forever and *returns no result*.

If I set `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` for debugging, the code runs fine, but synchronously.

**What could be the issue? Which steps can I take to find out?**

As OptaPy is a Python wrapper for a Java library, I suspect that Celery might not handle the additional thread well, but I don't know how to debug or fix this.

This is the Celery task in question, additional code can be provided on request:

```
@shared_task()
def schedule_task():

    solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig() \
        .withEntityClasses(Lesson) \
        .withSolutionClass(TimeTable) \
        .withConstraintProviderClass(define_constraints) \
        .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(30))

    solution = solver_factory_create(solver_config) \
        .buildSolver() \
        .solve(generate_problem())

    return str(solution)
```

Comment: This OptaPlanner use should be single-threaded because it uses the `SolverFactory` api (instead of the SolverManager one) and doesn't do '.withMoveThreadCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490364/948404) seems to apply here, too:

> By default celery uses the multiprocessing library as the concurrency implementation. [...] Unfortunately threads don't inherit after a subprocess has been forked, so a zombie is created.

Starting the Celery worker with the `--pool threads` option does the trick for me:

```
celery -A myapp worker --pool threads --loglevel=info
```